tqdm progress bar not updating when used with apply_async
I have a huge pandas dataframe and I want to do an operation on each row, so I wanted to use multiprocessing to accelerate the operation. Since tqdm is not pickleable, I decided to use a shared counter for each process. In theory, it should work, but I don't know why it doesn't. The progress bar doesn't update. I tried to have a separate progress bar for each worker, but even though it worked, the bars just kept overwriting each other, which also isn't neat.
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


class AAA:
    def __init__(
        ...
    ):
        ...

    ...

    @staticmethod
    def process_rows(chunk: pd.DataFrame, shared_locked, progress):
        ...

        for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
            ...
            with progress.get_lock():
                progress.value += 1
        return chunk

    def add_elevation_mp(self):
        ...

        shared_locked = (
            ...
        )

        num_rows = len(self.df)
        num_processes = mp.cpu_count()
        chunk_size = num_rows // num_processes
        chunks = [
            self.df_elevated[i : i + chunk_size]
            for i in range(0, len(self.df), chunk_size)
        ]

        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            progress_bar = tqdm(
                total=num_rows, desc="---progress bar"
            )
            progress = mp.Value("i", 0)
            processed_chunks = [
                pool.apply_async(
                    self.process_rows, args=(chunk, shared_locked, progress)
                )
                for chunk in chunks
            ]

            while True:
                if progress.value == num_rows:
                    break
                else:
                    progress_bar.update(progress.value)

            processed_chunks = [result.get() for result in processed_chunks]
            progress_bar.close()

        processed_df = pd.concat(processed_chunks)  # ignore_index=True

        self.df = processed_df
    ...



I believe your main problem is that you are trying to pass shared value progress as an argument to your worker function process_rows and this is resulting in an exception:
RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance

The solution is to use a multiprocessing pool initializer to initialize each pool process with a global progress variable.
You second problem is that you are not advancing the progress bar correctly. In your while True loop you are not setting the progress bar to the current value of progress.value but rather advancing the progress bar by progress.value steps.
But notice how your main process in executing its while True loop is burning up non-productive CPU cycles. You really only want to get the current value of progress.value when it has changed value and otherwise just go into a wait until that happens. For this we can use a multiprocessing.Condition instance:
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm


def init_pool(_progress, _progress_condition):
    global progress, progress_condition

    progress = _progress
    progress_condition = _progress_condition

class AAA:
    @staticmethod
    def process_rows(chunk):
        import time

        lock = progress.get_lock()

        for row in chunk:
            time.sleep(.1)
            with lock:
                progress.value += 1
                progress_condition.notify(1)

        return chunk


    def add_elevation_mp(self):
        rows = list(range(80))
        num_rows = len(rows)

        chunk_size = 10
        chunks = [
            rows[i:i+chunk_size]
            for i in range(0, len(rows), chunk_size)
        ]

        progress = mp.Value("i", 0)
        lock = progress.get_lock()
        progress_condition = mp.Condition(lock)
        with mp.Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(progress, progress_condition)) as pool:
            progress_bar = tqdm(total=num_rows, desc="---progress bar")

            async_results = [
                pool.apply_async(self.process_rows, args=(chunk,))
                for chunk in chunks
            ]

            last_progress = 0
            while last_progress != num_rows:
                with lock:
                    while (current_progress := progress.value) == last_progress:
                        progress_condition.wait()
                progress_bar.update(current_progress - last_progress)
                last_progress = current_progress

            processed_chunks = [async_result.get() for async_result in async_results]
            progress_bar.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    aaa = AAA()
    aaa.add_elevation_mp()

